# Javascript calculation using input and span fields

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity">
<span id="price">4000</span>

<input type="text" value="" id="total" readonly>
<input type="button" value="calculate Total Price" onClick="calculate()">
```

I need values from field `name="quantity"` and `id="price"` above and calculate using javascript function and to display it in field `id="total"` only when I click calculate button. I tried the javascript function below but the result is showing as `NaN`.

```
function calculate(tot) {
        var quan = document.getElementsByName('quantity').value;
        var pri = document.getElementById('price');
        var pr = parseInt(pri);
        var tot = quan * pr;
        document.getElementById("total").value = tot;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see a method in plural, such as `getElementsByName` it gets multiple elements, or what we call a nodeList, and even if there's only one matching element, you still get a nodeList, and a nodeList has no value, you can access a nodeList like an array and get the first element in the list like :

```
var quan = document.getElementsByName('quantity')[0].value;
```

Also, `getElementById` gets an element, not a number, you'd have to get the innerHTML

```
var pri = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
```

and remember the radix for `parseInt`

```
parseInt(pri, 10)
```

not that you really need to parse it when you're multiplying

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sm3wk5a0/)

Comment: Also `document.getElementById('price')` returns a dom element reference. Should be `document.getElementById('price').innerHtml`

Comment: I see you did iterations :)

Comment: If it's a price, they may want `parseFloat()` too ;).

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `for` loop and iterate over every individual value and put that in a value. Like this:

```
for(i=0; i<quan.length; i++) {

 var total+= quan[i];
}
```